# Best way to run multiple flask apps in a single docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

On a T2-Micro Instance on AWS/EC2 -

I have built four Docker containers as show in the .yaml file below.

These are:

1. Nginx
2. economy (app1)
3. elections (app2)
4. social (app3)

There are gunicorn web servers in each of the three app containers serving 1 flask app. These are Plot.ly/Dash apps.

As one might see, this takes a container for each app which gets bulky after three and starts to consume too much memory on the T2-Micro Instance.

What would be ideal is if each app container ie: economy, elections, social etc. could have multiple flask apps within, using port iteration such as 5000, 5001, 5002 etc. They would all be addressable by unique port numbers which could be enumerated in the .yaml file.

The use of single containers, single stacks of gunicorn, flask and dependent packages would reduce the memory requirements for individual containers allowing me to load up more apps on a single ec2 instance.

The .yaml file below:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  economy:
    container_name: economy
    hostname: economy
    restart: always
    build: economy
    networks:
      tsworker-net:
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/tmp/data:ro
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :8000 economy:server

  elections:
    container_name: elections
    hostname: elections
    restart: always
    build: elections
    networks:
      tsworker-net:
    expose:
      - "8500"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/tmp/data:ro
      - ./assets:/tmp/assets:ro
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
    command: gunicorn --log-level debug -w 1 -b :8500 elections:server

  social:
    container_name: social
    hostname: social
    restart: always
    build: social
    networks:
      tsworker-net:
    expose:
    - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/tmp/data:ro
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :9000 social:server # was 8000

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      tsworker-net:
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.http.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - /etc/letsencrypt/etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /etc/letsencrypt/www:/var/www/letsencrypt
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    depends_on:
      - economy
      - elections
      - social

networks:
  tsworker-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran an experiment and it seems that with 6 apps and an nginx container, I have a good amount of storage left. /dev/xvda1      8.3G  4.4G  3.9G  53% /

Comment: I may be able to put 10-12 apps per server (that will be 11 containers) without any issues. The Dash chart apps are pretty light as are container frames themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree that this breaks the docker principal, but i've used supervisord to run multiple services in a single container in the past with some success. It was a pain to troubleshoot when things went wrong so I ended up using several containers at the end of the project.

Documentation here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: I agree that separation of concerns would aid in development, maint. etc. It looks like I can stay with manual scaling of containers (adding more until I run out of space) for now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Docker principle is one service per container, so its not bad thinking having multiple containers for multiple instances. If you want to reduce resource usage, try using an alpine image in your Dockerfiles. Anyway, afaik container self memory usage if very low if not none, the main source of usage is the app.

What you are describing sounds like to scale the services manually, instead of using "docker-compose up --scale" https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

You could change the command by a supervisord that runs multiple times the gunicorn and expose the ports manually in docker-compose file... But thats a bit rare in docker "way of do things".

You may try to add "scale: 3" to one service and see if works well to you. Just note that using scale is not compatible with container_name, because it will scale the name too.

Hope it helps!